# How can I check null and assign new value in linq anonymous type to select expected sql result

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I am trying to select products with product image from **products** and **ProductImage** table where **ProductImages** table contain Images for **Products** and It can contain **Null** or **Many Images** for a single product.
I done this using sql query but not able to write the exact linq query

My **Products** Table is

```
 ID |  Name            
 ______________________
 1  | Masic Mouse      
 2  | IPhone X         
 3  | Thai Jeans pant  
 4  | Samsung Galaxy 8 
 5  | Apple Laptop     
 6  | round collar     
 7  | V collar t-shirt
```

My **ProductImages** Table is

```
 productId  | Image              |  ProductImageId
 _________________________________________________________________
 1          | 14_mm01.jpg        |  1
 2          | new-1.jpg          |  2
 3          | jeans pant.jpeg    |  3
 4          | 21_samsung.jpg     |  4
 4          | 21_samsungghf.jpg  |  5
 5          | images.jpg         |  6
 6          | 21502057.jpg       | 10
```

My **SQL** query for selecting new table

```
SELECT p.id, 
       p.NAME, 
       Isnull((SELECT TOP 1 image 
               FROM   productimages 
               WHERE  productid = p.id), 'noproductimage.jpg') AS image, 
       Isnull((SELECT TOP 1 Cast(id AS VARCHAR(50)) 
               FROM   productimages 
               WHERE  productid = p.id), 'NoId')               AS ProductImageId 
FROM   products p
```

Which gives me the exact result like

```
 ID |  Name            | Image               |  ProductImageId
 _________________________________________________________________
 1  | Masic Mouse      | 14_mm01.jpg         |  1
 2  | IPhone X         | new-1.jpg           |  2
 3  | Thai Jeans pant  | jeans pant.jpeg     |  3
 4  | Samsung Galaxy 8 | 21_samsung.jpg      |  4
 5  | Apple Laptop     | images.jpg          |  6
 6  | round collar     | 21502057.jpg        | 10
 7  | V collar t-shirt | noproductimage.jpg  | NoId
```

But When I am trying to do so using linq I am not getting expected result like the above **Table**.
My **LINQ** query for this selection is

```
var products = from p in db.Products
                       select new 
                       {
                          p.Id,
                          p.Name,
                          ProductImage = (from ppi in db.ProductImages where 
                          ppi.ProductId == p.Id
                          select ppi.Image),
                          ProductImageID = (from ppi in db.ProductImages
                                           where ppi.ProductId == p.Id
                                           select ppi.Id)
                       };
```

This **LINQ** query returning only one result

```
 ID |  Name            | Image               |  ProductImageId
 _________________________________________________________________
  1 | Masic Mouse      | 14_mm01.jpg         |  1
```

How do I get the expected result exactly like the **SQL** query returning??

Comment: MySQL and SQL Server are 2 totally different RDBMS. Please don't tag irrelevant ones when posting a question. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for that and thank @Larnu for remind me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be much faster if you would perform a GroupJoin on `Products` and `ProductImages`. If the product has any images, select the first name and Id
If there are no images, select "noProductImage" and "NoId"

```
var result = products.GroupJoin(productImages,  // GroupJoin products and productImages
    product => product.Id,                      // from every product take the Id
    image => image.ProductId,                   // from every image take the productId
    (product, images) => new                    // for every product with matching images make new:
    {
         ProductId = product.Id,
         Name = product.Name,
         Image = images
             .Select(image => image.Image) 
             .FirstOrDefault() ??             // select the first image name
              "noproductimage.jpg",           // or use a default if there is none

         ProductImageId = images
             .Select(image => image.ProductImageId.ToString())
             .FirstOrDefault() ??             // select the text of the first productId
             "NoId");                         // or use a default if there is none
    }
```

This statement has to check twice whether there are any images at all, just like your SQL statement.

Consider returning the image data as one sub class:

```
(product, images) => new        // for every product with matching images make new:
{
    ProductId = product.Id,
    Name = product.Name,
    ImageData = images.Select(image => new
    {
        Image = image.Image, 
        ProductImageId = image.ProductImageId.ToString(),
     })
     .FirstOrDefault() ??             // select the first image name
     new                              // or use a default if there is none
     {
          Image = "noproductImage.jpg",
          ProductImageId = "NoId",
     },
});
```

Final remark: Wouldn't it be better to return the ProductImageId as a number instead of text? Let number zero mean "No Id".

Answer (score 0):

```
var data =(from item in db.Product 
join item1 in db.productImage on item.id equals item1.productId select new{
 item.Id,
item.Name,
ProductImage = (item1.image==null)?”noproductimage.jpg” :item1.image,
productImageId= (item1.imageid==null) ?”NoId”: item1.imageid
}).groupBy(a=>a.productImageId).select(a=>a.firstOrDefault()).toList();
```

why dont you join two table ?

Comment: This linq query returning all **ProductImages** rows with multiple product  **Id**  where I want the  first or default **Image** and **ImageId**

Comment: I tried following your answer and that help me other than I am unable to add **"noproductimage.jpg"** and **"NoId"**.
But my code works with **NULL** and **0** respectively for**"noproductimage.jpg"** and **"NoId"**.

Thanks for the help @leila

Comment: add .groupby(a=>a.imageid).select(a=>a.firstordefault()).tolist(); at the end of  query to remove duplicate record